# Cancel email in memory from being sent

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

In my application i allow the user to change his password.

Currently, i have a listener for the preUpdate Event where i check if the password field changed, and if yes, i send an email to the user informing that his password has changed.

```
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if ($entity instanceof User) {

            if ($args->hasChangedField('password')) {
                // Send the email about the password been changed successfully
                $this->sendPasswordChangedSuccessfully($entity);
            }
        }
}
```

But the problem is, if an error happens(for example when commiting on the controller), the email is sent anyway even if the password didnt change.

Is there a way to prevent an email in memory from being sent? I could send the email on the controller, but i would like to make use of the events.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Doctrine, you can hook it to `Events::postUpdate`. Something like this:

```
class EmailListener implements EventSubscriber
{
        private $sendNotification = false;

        public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
        {
                $entity = $args->getEntity();

                if ($entity instanceof User) {

                    if ($args->hasChangedField('password')) {
                        $this->sendNotification = true;
                    }
                }
        }

        public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
        {
                if($this->sendNotification) {
                        // Send the email about the password been changed successfully
                        $this->sendPasswordChangedSuccessfully($eventArgs->getEntity());                
                }

        }        
}
```

You'll probably need also set $sendNotification to false once the email has been sent.